# Delphi: WebBrowser "ActiveX control" error

Tags: delphi, browser, activex

On some websites I navigate with `TWebBrowser`, after the loading of the site I get this:

> One or more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either:
>
> 1) Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on
>   this page or 2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls
>
> As a result, the page might not display correctly

I don't care if the page will display correctly or not, I just want it to display without this message! 
How to disable this?
I have tried to temporarily enable everything in the Internet Options but no success, the message still appears.

Comment: Do you have a sample URL, where we can try ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the 'silent' property?

Comment: Silent property does not prevent the ActiveX message to display.